# Prevent nginx proxy_pass 302

Tags: nginx

I have two server blocks defined on my server to perform various redirects. In the simplified example below a 302 redirect is issued. I would like to proxy this request transparently to the user.

How can I do this?

<del>When I use a location block defined as `location =/` a 200 is issued as expected.</del>

```
http {
    server {
        server_name acme;
        listen 80;
        include mime.types;

        # http://acme/web/style.css -> http://127.0.0.1:8080/web/style.css
        location ~^/web/.*$ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }

       # http://acme/style.css -> http://127.0.0.1:8080/acme/style.css
       location ~^(.+)$ {
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/acme$1;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for `nginx` to intercept the 302 response code and process internally. I set up a test scenario which worked using this:

```
location /some/uri/ {
    error_page 302 = @fallback;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    proxy_pass ...;
}
location @fallback {
    rewrite ^ /some/other/uri last;
}
```

This would of course be a blanket intercept without regard for the value of the response headers, but that may be adequate for your requirement. See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) and [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors) for more.

Comment: that `proxy_intercept_errors` saved my day